# How to search workspace symbols across multiple languages by using LSP in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, lsp

I want to search the workspace symbols across multiple languages without opening any buffer.

Like what VSCode can do:
[image]

I tried the following:

- Neovim built-in `vim.lsp.buf.workspace_symbol()`
- Telescope. nvim's `:Telescope lsp_dynamic_workspace_symbols` and `:Telescope lsp_workspace_symbols`
- Fzf-lua's `:FzfLua lsp_live_workspace_symbols` and `:FzfLua lsp_workspace_symbols`

But all themes only search the workspace symbols provided by the LSP servers attaching the current buffer.

Are there any other tools to provide this functionality? If not, is it possible to achieve this functionality in Neovim?

Comment: Have you tried `:grep` or using tags?

Answer (score 2):

```
:Telescope lsp_workspace_symbols query=searchTerm
```

There is a [bug](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim/issues/964) related to this, you need the `query=searchTerm`.